# Selecting values from List

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following List:

```
public class Products
{
 public string SKU;
 public int WarehouseID;
}

List<Products> products = new List<Products>();
```

which after populating the list I end up with the following data:

```
ProductCode|WarehouseID
SKU001|2
SKU001|3
SKU002|3
SKU003|3
SKU004|1
SKU004|5
```

I have multiple SKU's as the item can be supplied from more then one Warehouse location as it's in stock. In the case of SKU001, warehouse ID 2 has more stock than warehouse ID 3.

I need to select the items from the least number of warehouse locations. What I'm trying to end up with is something like

```
SKU001|3
SKU002|3
SKU003|3
SKU004|1
```

This limits product selection to only 2 locations as SKU001, SKU002 & SKU003 can all be obtained from warehouse ID 3. Ideally selecting from a location with the most stock but limiting the number of locations is more important.

I'm using Linq to try and achieve this while trying to loop each List item but am struggling as Linq's not a strong point for me. I tried to first get the highest count of repeating warehouse id's using

```
products.GroupBy(i => i).OrderByDescending(grp => grp.Count()).Select(grp => grp.Key).FirstOrDefault();
```

but am getting lost on the rest of the items. Any ideas on how I could achive this?

Comment: I don't get what is the expected output's logic. I tried, cant get it, Can somebody explain?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel the expected output is to have distinct SKU's (ProductCodes) from the lease number of Warehouse Locations (ID's).

Comment: @KDee Then how `SKU001|3` came in output. It should be `SKU001|2` right?

Comment: @L.B that does give me unique SKU's but no warehouse ID's so I don't know what location the SKU's are at? Is it easy to add the WarehouseID to the output so I have a List of SKU's and Warehouse ID's?

Comment: @SriramSakthivel SKU001|3 appears in the output as I need the least number of locations. As 3 items can be supplied from warehouse ID 3 then that is why it will be in the output. IF SKU001|2 was in the output then it would increase the locations to 3 instead of 2.

Comment: `GroupBy(i=>i.SKU).OrderBy(i=>i.WarehouseID)`

Comment: No doubt question is a bit confusing, and after reading the answers below I am wondering that I am missing a whole lot. Anyway @KDee, I guess you are almost there, you are just missing 1 tiny thing in your LINQ, `GroupBy`, you should do like `(i => i.WarehouseID)`, this should do the trick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in multiple statements, first Get `WarehouseID` along with distinct products in each warehouse and their count like:

```
var query = products.GroupBy(r => r.WarehouseID)
                    .Select(grp => new
                    {

                        WarehouseID = grp.Key,
                        DistinctProducts = grp.Select(r => r.SKU).Distinct(),
                        DistinctCount = grp.Select(r => r.SKU).Distinct().Count(),
                    });
```

Later create a result list like:

```
List<Products> result = new List<Products>();

foreach (var item in query.OrderByDescending(r => r.DistinctCount)) //warehouse with most products
{
    if (!result.Any(r => item.DistinctProducts.Any(t => t == r.SKU)))
    {
        result.AddRange(item.DistinctProducts.Select(r => new Products { SKU = r, WarehouseID = item.WarehouseID }));
    }
}
```

For output:

```
foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} | {1}", item.SKU, item.WarehouseID);
}
```

Output:

```
SKU001 | 3
SKU002 | 3
SKU003 | 3
SKU004 | 1
```

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I doubt your algorithm is guaranteed to produce optimal result. Let's say warehouses have products: 1:(1,2), 2:(3,4), 3:(5,6), 4:(1,2,3), 5:(2,3,4), 6:(3,4,5). Your algorithm will prefer large warehouses which can't cover all products, but optimal solution includes small ones. I also don't like performing the same query multiple times (I doubt compiler will optimize that). (I haven't compiled the code and may be wrong.)

Comment: @Habib that's great, did exactly what I asked for. Thanks for that. On a side note, how easy would it be for me to pass other class data to the final result List. eg if I have OrderID in my class I would want that passed through, how do I select that and add to the range when populating the result List?

Comment: @Habib, got it. I select it using `OrderID = grp.Select(r => r.OrderID).ToArray()` and then access it using `OrderID = item.OrderID[0].ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**
I've updated my query to select based on the number of products stocked in each warehouse, not the stock of each product.

```
var productQ2 = products.GroupBy(product => product.WarehouseId)
                        .SelectMany(wGroup => wGroup.Select(product => new
                                                                        {
                                                                            Product = product,
                                                                            WarehouseProductCount = wGroup.Select(p => p.SKU)
                                                                                                          .Distinct()
                                                                                                          .Count()
                                                                        }))
                        .GroupBy(product => product.Product.SKU)
                        .Select(pGroup => pGroup.OrderByDescending(product => product.WarehouseProductCount).First().Product);
```

---

**Original answer:**

There is no way to access the amount of stock in each warehouse, so you need to add that to the model.

```
public class Product
{
 public string SKU;
 public int WarehouseID;
 public int StockCount;
}

List<Product> products = new List<Product>();
```

Then to get your query results:

```
products.GroupBy(product => product.SKU)
        .Select(group => group.OrderByDescending(product => product.StockCount).First())
```

Comment: Having a `StockCount` with each product for a warehouse is weird.

Comment: Okay - I think I misunderstood the question. *Awks*

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution which produces minimal set of warehouse ids:

```
// Number of product SKUs
int nProducts = products.Select(p => p.SKU).Distinct().Count();
// Warehouses and their products
Dictionary<int, List<Product>> warehouses = products
    .GroupBy(p => p.WarehouseID)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.ToList());
List<int> minWarehouseSet = warehouses
    // Get list of unique warehouse ids
    .Select(p => p.Key).ToList()
    // Get all combinations of warehouses
    .Combinations()
    // Order sets by the number of items
    .OrderBy(ws => ws.Count())
    // Find set which satisfies requirement (contains all products)
    .First(ws => ws.SelectMany(w => warehouses[w]).Distinct().Count() == nProducts)
    .ToList();
foreach (var product in products.Where(p => minWarehouseSet.Contains(p.WarehouseID)))
    Console.WriteLine("{0}|{1}", product.SKU, product.WarehouseID);
```

It requires the following extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<IEnumerable<T>> Combinations<T>(this IList<T> allValues)
{
    for (int counter = 0; counter < (1 << allValues.Count); ++counter)
        yield return allValues.Where((_, i) => (counter & 1 << i) == 0).ToList();
}
```

Output:

```
SKU001|3
SKU002|3
SKU003|3
SKU004|5
```

Notes:

1. This solution performs a brute-force search for the optimal set of warehouses. Probably there's a better solution.
2. The number of warehouses is limited to the number of bits in `int` from `Cominations` method (which is 32). You can choose a different variable type or implement the method in a different way.
3. Data you have provided does not include stock and you haven't specified how it affects the result. If you need stock to be taken into account, adjust ordering (for measuring "quality" of result) or filtering (for strict conditions).